# Mail send by server gets denied by mx.hotmail.com

Tags: smtp, vps, deny

I got an notice that some clients werent receiving their emails, all clients used hotmail accounts, while i looked into logs i got this part

```
Sep 25 07:52:51 s22090 named[25045]: client 127.0.0.1#44056: query (cache) 'hotmail.com/MX/IN' denied
Sep 25 07:52:51 ...#56174: query (cache) 'mx2.hotmail.com/A/IN' denied
Sep 25 07:52:51 ...#59417: query (cache) 'mx2.hotmail.com/AAAA/IN' denied
Sep 25 07:52:51 ...#54682: query (cache) 'mx1.hotmail.com/A/IN' denied
Sep 25 07:52:51 ...#60299: query (cache) 'mx1.hotmail.com/AAAA/IN' denied
Sep 25 07:52:51 ...#54353: query (cache) 'mx4.hotmail.com/A/IN' denied
Sep 25 07:52:51 ...#55171: query (cache) 'mx4.hotmail.com/AAAA/IN' denied
Sep 25 07:52:51 ...#55501: query (cache) 'mx3.hotmail.com/A/IN' denied
Sep 25 07:52:51 ...#33547: query (cache) 'mx3.hotmail.com/AAAA/IN' denied
Sep 28 06:39:52 ...#52626: query (cache) 'd7ddfeb7120a9845bbb8f56e789c4f.pamx1.hotmail.com/A/IN' denied
Sep 28 06:39:52 ...#44450: query (cache) 'd7ddfeb7120a9845bbb8f56e789c4f.pamx1.hotmail.com/AAAA/IN' denied
```

Which i cant really understand why it blocks/denies, anyone can help?

## edit

```
Return-Path:    <spedeus@s22090.vps.name-servers.gr>
X-Spam-Checker-Version: SpamAssassin 3.3.1 (2010-03-16) on s22090.vps.name-servers.gr
X-Spam-Level:   **
X-Spam-Status:  No, score=2.4 required=5.0 tests=HTML_IMAGE_ONLY_20, HTML_MESSAGE,HTML_MIME_NO_HTML_TAG,MIME_HTML_ONLY,NO_RELAYS autolearn=no version=3.3.1
X-Original-To:  info@spedeus.com
Delivered-To:   info.spedeus@s22090.vps.name-servers.gr
Received:   by s22090.vps.name-servers.gr (Postfix, from userid 507) id 3BDC9192511F; Wed, 7 Oct 2015 14:35:57 -0400 (EDT)
To: info@spedeus.com
Subject:    xxxxx
X-PHP-Originating-Script:   507:class.phpmailer.php
Date:   Wed, 7 Oct 2015 14:35:57 -0400
From:   "Spedeus.com" <noreply@spedeus.com>
Message-ID: <b1ea97c7e45bfc0362e77ee9d6470b0c@www.spedeus.com>
X-Priority: 3
X-Mailer:   PHPMailer 5.2.1 (http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/)
MIME-Version:   1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding:  8bit
Content-Type:   text/html; charset="UTF-8"
```

the DNS records

```
mail    A - IPv4 Address    185.25.22.90
spedeus.com MX - Mail Server    5 mail.spedeus.com.
spedeus.com SPF - Sender Permitted From v=spf1 a mx a:spedeus.com ip4:185.25.22.90 ?all
```

## edit2

```
Oct  8 05:33:24 s22090 postfix/pickup[13686]: 9AD7619265B0: uid=0 from=<info@spedeus.com>
Oct  8 05:33:24 s22090 postfix/cleanup[15659]: 9AD7619265B0: message-id=<1444296804.15654@spedeus.com>
Oct  8 05:33:24 s22090 postfix/qmgr[13687]: 9AD7619265B0: from=<info@spedeus.com>, size=602, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Oct  8 05:33:26 s22090 postfix/smtp[15661]: 9AD7619265B0: to=<xxxxx@hotmail.com>, relay=mx4.hotmail.com[65.55.37.104]:25, delay=2.1, delays=0.12/0.01/0.64/1.3, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250  <1444296804.15654@spedeus.com> Queued mail for delivery)
Oct  8 05:33:26 s22090 postfix/qmgr[13687]: 9AD7619265B0: removed
```

As i see, it gets removed from queue after queued for delivery.

Comment: Your email logs would be more helpful than your named logs here.

Comment: @JennyD i updated with the maillog entries, but i dont think it supplies any  useful information or am i missing something

Comment: It shows some very useful information indeed - namely that Hotmail accepted the email for delivery. This means that whatever causes the non-delivery is happening **within** their system. (it's most likely their antispam algorithms - did your recipients check their spam folders?)

Comment: @JennyD yes they double-checked i even created an account just so i could check it, the email never goes through , not even in junk folders and the settings in email about spam are the default ones. So i assume that is something internal of the hotmail system.

Comment: It is definitely something internal with them. They have been silently discarding mail for a long time now, without informing either the sender or the recipient.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you need have/check a reverse dns entry on the domain from which the emails exit your network. How does the headers look like? Does delivering to gmail work?

---

Some are suggesting setting up [DKIM](http://www.dkim.org/#introduction).
If available I'd recommend (instead of trying to hack your config to fool headers) is to see if you can use a `relay` to send emails from that server instead, a designated mail server somewhere on your network such as Exchange. In that case (and it looks like you're using postfix) 
in `/etc/postfix/main.cf` add a line `relayhost = 10.x.x.x` the IP being said relay server IP

Comment: Delivering to gmail/yahoo/other is successful. About the headers, i dont get a mail delivery failure so i assume you ask for headers of the mail i send?

Comment: Yes the sent emails to see what domain of yours is listed in there and if it's a valid one like mail.yourcompany.com or something

Comment: updated the question with the mail headers, please take a look